# Elasticsearch while doing update operation , to select that particular index getting exception

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, model-view-controller, elasticsearch-net

In am new in elasticsearch and i am trying to do update operation with elasticsearch but for that when am trying to filter and select that particular code i am getting execption and the exception is:

> An exception of type 'ElasticsearchCRUD.ElasticsearchCrudException' occurred in ElasticsearchCRUD.dll but was not handled in user code,
>   Additional information: ElasticSearchContextGet: HttpStatusCode.BadRequestNo handler found for uri [//skillwithlistofdetailss/skillwithlistofdetails/1] and method [GET]

and my method is below:

```
public void UpdateSkill(long updateId, string updateName, string updateDescription, List<SkillDetail> updateSkillDetailsList)
    {
        using (var context = new ElasticsearchContext(ConnectionString, _elasticSearchMappingResolver))
        {
            //var addressItem = _elasticsearchContext.SearchById<SkillWithListOfDetails>(updateId);
            //var entityAddress = _entityFrameworkContext.Address.First(t => t.Id == addressItem.Id);
            try
            {
                var skill = context.GetDocument<SkillWithListOfDetails>(updateId);

                skill.Updated = DateTime.UtcNow;
                skill.Name = updateName;
                skill.Description = updateDescription;
                skill.SkillDetails = updateSkillDetailsList;

                foreach (var item in skill.SkillDetails)
                {
                    item.Updated = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }

                context.AddUpdateDocument(skill, skill.Id);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

        }
    }
```

and i am getting exception in this line of code:--

**var skill = context.GetDocument(updateId);**

Comment: This part of the error is interesting to me:

[//skillwithlistofdetailss/skillwithlistofdetails/1]

Are you specifying your index anywhere before this section of code somehow (default index) ? Also the fact that the URI has skillwithlistofdetailss has two "s". Is that intentional?

Comment: yes i did that correctly.... by this code i can get the index value in sense GET http://localhost:9200/skillwithlistofdetailss/skillwithlistofdetails/_search

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit the question to provide the index structure for us?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with index/type name somewhere? The error message says: "ElasticSearchContextGet: HttpStatusCode.BadRequestNo handler found for uri [//skillwithlistofdetailss/skillwithlistofdetails/1] and method [GET]:".

Check your index and type are correct or not.

> Index:  skillwithlistofdetailss
>
> Type: skillwithlistofdetails